# how to shift all parameters in a batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, parameters, shift

The well-know `shift` command can be used to shift positional parameters in batch file, BUT it does not affect the special variable `%*`.

[The shift command has no effect on the %* batch parameter.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732231.aspx)

Is there an alternative for shifting `%°`?

Comment: batch is torture.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no, there is no built in syntax to do what you want. The best you can do is use a loop to build a variable containing the desired list of parameters. Each iteration adds `%1` to the list and then shifts. The loop continues until there are no more parameters.

This will only work if the parameters do not contain any unquoted poison characters.

```
@echo off

shift /1
shift /1

set "remainingArgs="
:getRemainingArgs
if "%~1" neq "" (
  set ^"remainingArgs=%remainingArgs% %1"
  shift /1
  goto :getRemainingArgs
)
echo remainingArgs=%remainingArgs%
```